# Bound over sample probability

Tags: bounds

I have a discrete random variable $x \sim \text{Cat}(\textbf{p})$. What I'm trying to compute is the probability that any sample $x$ has an associated probability of at least $\alpha$. I would compute this as:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p_i \in \textbf{p}:\, p_i > \alpha} p_i
\end{equation}
However, I'm not interested in the precise vaue. What I'm looking for is any lowerbound over this quantity, if it exists.

Any hint or reference is appreciated. I feel like this quantity could be linked to the entropy/information or others, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are asking about or even what would constitute an answer, because it looks like any answer would simply have to examine your particular probability distribution.  There certainly isn't enough information given here to establish any kind of general lower bound.  Could you clarify what you intend by "any sample $x$ has an associated probability of at least $\alpha$"?  What do you mean by "sample," what event does this "probability" refer to, what does "associated" mean, and what is your implicit quantifier (at least one sample, all samples, something else)?

Comment: First, the support of x is a finite set (say of size N). Using integer values {1, ..,N} as domain, $p_i$ is the probability for $x = i$. Suppose I draw a sample $j$ from $\textbf{p}$. I'm asking whether it is possible to provide a lower-bound for the probability of the event: $p_j > \alpha$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's not enough information.  What size is your sample?  Also, $p_j\gt\alpha$ is not an event: it's a property of the distribution, separate from any sample.  Are you trying to say you draw a *single realization* from this distribution and the event consists of all values with individual probabilities exceeding a prespecified threshold $\alpha$? And is your bound intended to apply to *any* such distribution? If so, there are two answers: one for $\alpha\le 1/N$ and another for $\alpha\gt 1/N$--and that fact alone should make it clear what those answers are!

Comment: There may be no sensible answer or theorems related to what I'm asking, apart from trivial bounds. That is acceptable. Still, $p_j > \alpha$ is an event, because I'm not asking whether $p_j$ satisfies this for all $j$. Also, I can compute the probability of what I'm describing as the summation written in the question. If we consider the extreme case of the uniform distribution, the quantity jumps from 1 to 0, as you describe